# Control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have created [**super template**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-starter-super) ionic project.I have never used this template before.So can you tell me what is the user name and password should I use with this? It doesn't allow me to create one too.It gives below error.Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad :(

[**Doc**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-starter-super#user)

> The User provider is used to authenticate users through its
>   login(accountInfo) and signup(accountInfo) methods, which perform POST
>   requests to an API endpoint that you will need to configure.